# non-system users of CentOS8

Tags: linux, centos, centos8

How can I pick only non-system users in Linux? How it depends on their ID? [I need smth like this. Don't pay attention to the date. It's unnecessary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/socEp.png)

That I have now, how to continue?

```
#!/bin/bash

now=$(date --date "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d") -2 month" +%F)

for i in $(cat /etc/passwd | awk -F: '{print $1 ":" $3}'); do
        id=$(echo $i | awk -F: '{print $2}')
        name=$(echo $i | awk -F: '{print $1}')
```

Answer (score 1):

The non-system users have ID greater than 1000 and != 65534

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).